# Bootstrap Responsiveness when keyboard is open in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on an AngularJS project for a tablet with the basic navigation through all the different pages. The project consists of all the basic features like Side Navigation Menu, a Header, the links of different pages, and a Footer.

The project is also created responsively using Bootstrap. I am not facing any responsiveness issue in all the elements created in the project except one.

**When keyboard opens, the responsiveness gets disturbed**.

Basically, the header div position gets distorted, the footer shifts above and gets placed right above the keyboard opened, and the side-navigation width also gets disturbed.

I tried the following things -

- Used `position: fixed`, `position: relative` but nothing changed.
- Looked into many different SO question links but got no fruitful result.

I have one option *(hack)* left that is stated [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392169/footer-is-pushed-up-when-keyboard-is-open-html-css) given by Roberrrt but that's a long process and I'm short on time and doubt if it will be a positive hack.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

**Update :-**

Giving an idea of how the structure of my project is -

This is the main page where a search box that is in-built in **DataTables** is used. The Header, Footer and Side-Navigation Burger Menu Button are as described here.
[image]

When clicked on the Burger menu, the side-nav opens in full-width as shown below -
[image]

Now on clicking the search box the following screen shows with all the elements distorted and responsiveness screwed -
[image]

**For reference purpose, The theme that I'm working on is Inspinia**

Comment: Should probably include your basic html layout, no content just structure.

Comment: @KreepN have updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: I took a look and this will probably not help you in terms of finding a fix, but you could try commenting out the different sections of your page that are becoming distorted when the keypad opens and see if you can pinpoint a specific html element as the root of your issues. The footed behavior is expected, and it seems that most fixes implement a CSS fix type of fix that uses min-height on a parent container somewhere on the page. Sorry I couldn't help more, just hard to guesswhat the issue is with no hands-on the code.

Comment: @KreepN okay thanks, I'll see into it. The problem is that there are many elements whose styling I need to change in order to try and get some kind of _fix_ for this. And the whole project being a big one I can't share the code too as there are many different files and sharing all of them wouldn't be possible. Anyways, in case if you get any fix for this or any tryout then let me know.